# Bitwise Shift - Getting different results in C#.net vs PHP

Tags: c#, php, vb.net, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

When I run this command in PHP, I get:

```
Code: 2269495617392648 >> 24
Result: 32
```

When I run it in C#.net or vb.net, I get:

```
Code: 2269495617392648 >> 24
Result: 135272480
```

PHP is correct.

The interesting thing is, that when I try to shift any number greater than `int32` in .net, it yields bad results..

Every number under `int32 (2147483647)` yields the same results from php and c#.net or vb.net

Is there a workaround for this in .net?

Comment: It's been a while since I last used C#, but I believe your issue could be related to the fact PHP isn't strongly typed and it deduces your variable types in runtime, so it will give you a big variable type if you needed. I THINK your variable in C# is being overflown, so maybe using a bigger type will help. Is there an int64 type in C#? either that or maybe long long.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strictly speaking, PHP is wrong.

The entire bit pattern of the number `2269495617392648` is:

```
1000 0001 0000 0001 1000 0010 0000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0000 1000 (2269495617392648)
```

Right shifting this 24 times gets you:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0001 0000 0001 1000 0010 0000 (135272480)
```

This is the bit pattern for `135272480`, not `32`.

What's going on in PHP apparently is that the number `2269495617392648` is being truncated to `538447880` by perserving only the lower 32 bits. Note that the number `2269495617392648` is much too big to fit in a 32-bit integer, signed or unsigned.

Right shifting the truncated bits 24 times gives us `32`.

```
Before truncation to 32-bits:
1000 0001 0000 0001 1000 0010 0000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0000 1000 (2269495617392648)

After truncation to 32-bits:
0010 0000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0000 1000 (538447880)

Right shifting the truncated bits by 24 bits:
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 (32)
```

You have alluded to this problem when you said:

> The interesting thing is, that when I
>   try to shift any number greater then
>   int32 in .net it yields bad results..

It gives you bad results because some bits are being chopped off in order to fit in 32 bits.

If you're porting from PHP to C# and need to preserve this behavior, you need to manually truncate the bits by using `2269495617392648 & 0xffffffff` instead of just `2269495617392648` (see [jcomeau_ictx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006574/bitwise-shift-getting-different-results-in-c-net-vs-php/6006589#6006589)). But be aware that there is an issue of bit truncation going on in your PHP code. I'm not certain if it's intentional or not.

Answer (score 3):

bitwise-AND your number with 0xffffffff before shifting.

in Python:

```
>>> 2269495617392648 >> 24
135272480L
>>> (2269495617392648 & 0xffffffff) >> 24
32L
```

I rarely use .net, but fairly sure the syntax will be very similar.